# How to prevent a specific program from reading my files?

Tags: windows-10, file-access

My issue is more towards blocking a specific application/program (In this case, the Epic Games Launcher) from accessing my files. I know the best answer is just to remove that software. The reason that isn't an option is because the Unreal Engine in its newest version is only available on there.

For a specific example of its accessing of different programs not necessarily files, is that it checks my friends' lists on other programs without me giving it permission, and then makes recommendations even citing that I have friends on that platform that follow that recommendation.

I'm not sure if this is possible, and if it is, I would very much appreciate any help regarding it.

Comment: Is it possible to have the process run under a specific user account, and give that user account deny permissions on everything except it's specific folder?

Comment: Can you run it in a VM?

Comment: ...Do you just want the Engine itself, to create games?  You can build the engine and editors from source (private GitHub repository, but signup is trivial).

Comment: Although these are all valid solutions that I may use, I'm trying to see if anyone knows of a way to just block a specific program from accessing anything. I understand I'm being picky. Just attempting to see if anyone might know of a surefire way or anti-virus type software that may do this.

Comment: @NoahPersons Windows permissions are based on user account. Whatever account launches a program gets that's user's permissions to access anything that user can. In short, you would need to run the program with a different user.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of any software providing this functionality, but Windows itself gives you two options

1. run it under an account (`runas` command) that does not have permission to access your sensitive files
2. run it in a sandbox/virtual environment like HyperV or VirtualBox so your sensitive files literally don't exist in the context of the executing program

Answer (score 1):

The keyword to search for this software is **HIPS**, usually provided by some anti-virus software.

Currently, I use software that allows you to create custom rules to control which application can read/write/create/delete specified directories/files.

Windows NTFS ACLs support AppContainer-based rules and Windows uses it to protect apps from Microsoft Store. But it seems that there is no interface for users to configure that.

Comment: Windows does _NOT_ support application-based access control entries (ACEs) in ACLs; what you are seeing are _AppContainer_-specific ACEs. The distinction is important; an AppContainer might contain multiple applications, or a given application may be able to run both inside and not inside of an AppContainer. However, you're correct that there's no user-friendly way to sandbox a third-party app using an appcontainer; generally, that's something the developer is expected to do.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/appcontainer-for-legacy-applications- for more info about appcontainers and using them for legacy apps. Suffice to say, it's a useful sandbox that can achieve what you want, but the app has to be written such that it both uses, and requires, the sandbox.